# how to write plugin for adding extra button in jenkins (The button should be displayed in every job build)

Tags: jenkins, gradle, groovy

When we click on build number for a job, a page specific to job build number appears. I want to add extra button on the left side of that page.
When I click on that button, some task will be performed specific to that build.

Thanks,

Comment: Have you checked jenkins plugins code? You will have to write one for your need. (Question will be closed as too broad.. )

Comment: Yes, I checked the plugins code. It says we have to write in jelly but I don't understand where do I have to write the code.

Comment: Please check https://github.com/jenkinsci/rebuild-plugin/tree/master/src/main for a sample.